# React Native, fetch after async function

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, async-await, fetch

I have a problem that I do not know how to solve...

I have an api token saved in AsyncStorage, and when I want do fetch to rest I need this api token, but I do not know how to do it.

> I have file Functions.js with AsyncStorage functions.

```
async retrieveItem(key) {
  try {
    const retrievedItem =  await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    const item = JSON.parse(retrievedItem);
    return item;
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn(error.message);
  }
},
getApiToken: function(){
   try {
        return Functions.retrieveItem('api_token');
      } catch (error) {
        console.warn(error.message);
      }
    },
```

> File with fetch functions. (Api.js)

I tested with an asynchronous function, but not found...

```
async get(url) {

    try {
        var api = await Functions.getApiToken();

        if (!api)
            api = "";

        let opt = {
            method: 'get',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }),
        };

        return fetch(baseUrl + url + api, opt);
    } catch (error){
        console.warn(error);
    }       

},
```

When I did the fetch function, it worked for me without problems

> And the screen file Home.js

```
componentDidMount() {

  Api.get('home').then( response => {
    this.setState({
        profiles: response.profiles,
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please modify your Functions.js code a bit -

```
async retrieveItem(key) {
  try {
    const retrievedItem = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    const item = JSON.parse(retrievedItem);
    return item;
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn(error.message);
  }
},

async getApiToken{
  try {
    let token = await retrieveItem('api_token');
    return token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn(error.message);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you!